# Pivot Table Order by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a pivot table for sales per month, I would like to order the data by the current month. I wondered if I could use a case statement and order by; I have tried this below (not working though);

DB Server: SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT txt_web_name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 1 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 2 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 3 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 4 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 5 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 6 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 7 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 8 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 9 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 10 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'October',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 11 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 12 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'December'
FROM tbl_payment
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orders ON (uid_pay_orderid = uid_orders)
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_websites ON (uid_order_webid = uid_websites)
WHERE dbo.tbl_payment.bit_pay_paid = 1
GROUP BY txt_web_name
ORDER BY 
        CASE 

         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 'January'
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 THEN 'February'
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 3 THEN 'March'
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 4 THEN 'April'
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 THEN 'May'
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 6 THEN 'June'
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 7 THEN 'July'
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 THEN 'August'
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 9 THEN 'September'
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 THEN 'October'
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 11 THEN 'November'
         WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 THEN 'December' 

         END  DESC
```

Comment: What are you trying to order? Are you trying to change the position of the columns? *(So that in March the columns start with March and end with February?)*  Or are you trying to order the data so that in March the data is ordered by the values in the March column?  Or are you trying to achieve something else? Maybe an example of the output you want would help?

Comment: Hi Everyone, sorry for late reply got called into a meeting. Thank you for all your responses, i will definitely look into the pivot table route and report back. In fact someone posted an answer, which worked using my query, however it is no longer here??. I will look into the pivot tables below, seems a lot cleaner. I will report back and tick the right answer.  @dems I am trying to order data not columns.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently sorting by a constant value (ie - the name of the month), which as you've found, won't have any effect.

You need something like

```
 ORDER BY
     CASE MONTH(GETDATE()) 
     WHEN 1 THEN January
     WHEN 2 THEN February
     ...
     END
```

PS. Do you know that SQL Server has a `PIVOT` command...

```
select * 
from 
(
    select txt_web_name, mon_pay_amount, datename(month,dte_pay_paydate) as mpd 
    FROM tbl_payment  
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orders ON (uid_pay_orderid = uid_orders)  
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_websites ON (uid_order_webid = uid_websites)  
    WHERE dbo.tbl_payment.bit_pay_paid = 1  
    AND txt_pay_type<>'credit'
) t
pivot
(
    sum(mon_pay_amount) for mpd in 
    ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August], .....)
)p
order by
   case MONTH(getdate())
       when 1 then [January]
       when 2 then [February]
        ...
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT txt_web_name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 1 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS January,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 2 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS February,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 3 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS March,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 4 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS April,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 5 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS May,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 6 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS June,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 7 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS July,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 8 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS August,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 9 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS September,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 10 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS October,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 11 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS November,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dte_pay_paydate) = 12 AND txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' THEN mon_pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS December
FROM tbl_payment
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orders ON (uid_pay_orderid = uid_orders)
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_websites ON (uid_order_webid = uid_websites)
WHERE dbo.tbl_payment.bit_pay_paid = 1
GROUP BY txt_web_name
ORDER BY 
        CASE MONTH(GETDATE()) 
         WHEN 1 THEN January
         WHEN 2 THEN February
         WHEN 3 THEN March
         WHEN 4 THEN April
         WHEN 5 THEN May
         WHEN 6 THEN June
         WHEN 7 THEN July
         WHEN 8 THEN August
         WHEN 9 THEN September
         WHEN 10 THEN October
         WHEN 11 THEN November
         WHEN 12 THEN December 

         END  DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change this to use a `PIVOT` function. This would clean up the query to not use all of the `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT txt_web_name, 
    txt_pay_type, 
    DATENAME(month, dte_pay_paydate) mth,  -- get the month name instead of the number
    mon_pay_amount
  FROM tbl_payment
  INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orders 
    ON (uid_pay_orderid = uid_orders)
  INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_websites 
    ON (uid_order_webid = uid_websites)
  WHERE dbo.tbl_payment.bit_pay_paid = 1
    and txt_pay_type <> 'Credit'
) x
PIVOT
(
  sum(mon_pay_amount)
  for mth in([January], [February], [March], [April], [May],
            [June], [July], [August], September, [October], 
            [November], [December])
)p
order by 
  case datename(month, getdate()) 
    when 'January' then January 
    when 'February' then February  
    when 'March' then March  
    when 'April' then April  
    when 'May' then May  
    when 'June' then June  
    when 'July' then July  
    when 'August' then August  
    when 'September' then September  
    when 'October' then October  
    when 'November' then November  
    when 'December' then December  
  END Desc
```

Comment: `DATENAME(month, getdate())` is a constant.  Every row of data has the same result for this function.  This means that it doesn't change the order of the data at all... Unless I've missed something?

Comment: They are trying to change the columns to `ORDER BY` based on the result of `GetDate()` so if you execute today you will `ORDER BY` the August column but if you execute in September it will `ORDER BY` that column.  This appears to be what they are trying to do, unless I am missing something - that is what the current `ORDER BY` is doing

Comment: Have you tested this? It is not my experience that this statement will order by a different field depending on when it is executed. `ORDER BY DATENAME(month, myField)`, for example, wouldn't order by different columns.  When running it today it will simply be `ORDER BY 'August'` as opposed to `ORDER BY table.August`, no different from `ORDER BY 'this is a string'`...

Comment: @Dems you are right, its too early. Fixed thanks for pointing that out.